# Toggle modal with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, class, toggle, toggleclass

I'm used to working with jQuery but I'm trying to get back to vanilla javascript. I have a link that when clicked will reveal an account modal.

I also want to change the class of the modal when clicked to 'modal-visible'. This works as expected, but then when I click the link again to close the modal, I need the class to change back to 'modal-hidden'.

I wondered if someone could help me with that. Perhaps it needs a toggle instead?

```
var accountModal = document.getElementById("account-modal");
document.querySelector('#account-photo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    accountModal.classList.add('modal-visible');
    accountModal.classList.remove('modal-hidden');
    accountModal.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');
});

<a id="account-photo" href="/customer" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">Account</a>
<div id="account-modal" class="modal-visible" aria-label="Account Information" aria-hidden="false">Account Info</div>
```

Comment: You could use `accountModal.classList.toggle('modal-visible');` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing it if we assume it always begins closed:

```
document.querySelector('#account-photo').addEventListener('click', function() {var is_visible = false; return function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!is_visible) {
      accountModal.classList.add('modal-visible');
      accountModal.classList.remove('modal-hidden');
      accountModal.setAttribute('aria-hidden', !is_visible);
      is_visible = true;
    } else {
      accountModal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
      accountModal.classList.add('modal-hidden');
      accountModal.setAttribute('aria-hidden', !is_visible);
      is_visible = false;
    }
}});
```

This method basically acts as a manually coded toggle.

Comment: I would only change it to an immediately invoked function in order to not pollute the namespace. E.g. `(function() {var is_visible = false; return function(e) { ... })()` (you could also set `is_visible` to the opposite of `aria-hidden`)

Comment: That is more effective, thanks I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @BarryDoyle. It looks like the preventDefault isn't working on the account link so it tries to go to the customer page instead of showing the modal.